# mySQL complicated conditional join queries for efficiency over multiple queries and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

Weirdly I have done a lot of development with mySQL and never encountered some of the things I have encountered todays.

So, I have a user_items table

```
ID | name
---------
1  | test
```

I then have an item_data table

```
ID | item | added | info
-------------------------
1  | test | 12345 | important info
2  | test | 23456 | more recent important info
```

I then have an emails table

```
ID | added | email
1  | 12345 | old@b.com
2  | 23456 | a@b.com
3  | 23456 | b@c.com
```

and an emails_verified table

```
ID | email
-----------
1  | a@b.com
```

Now I appreciate the setup of these tables may not be efficient etc, but this cannot be changed, and is a lot more complex than it may seem.

What i want to do is as follows. I want to be able to search through a users items and display the associated info, as well as any emails associated, as well as displaying if the email has been verified.

```
user_items.name = item_data.item
item_data.added = emails.added
emails.email = emails_verified.email
```

So for user item 1, test. I want to be able to return its ID, its name, **the most recent** information, the most recent emails, and their verification status.

So I woud like to return

```
ID => 1
name => test
information => more recent important info
emails => array('0' => array('email' => 'a@b.com' , 'verified' => 'YES'),'1' => array('email' => 'b@c.com' , 'verified' => 'NO'))
```

Now I could do this with multiple queries with relative ease. My research however suggests that this is significantly more resource/time costly then using one (albeit very complex) mysql query with loads of join statements.

The reason using one query would also would be useful (I believe) is because I can then add search functionality with relative ease - adding to the query complex where statements.

To further complicated matters I am using CodeIgniter. I cannot be too picky :) so any none CI answers would still be very useful.

The code I have got thus far is as follows. It is however very much 'im not too sure what im doing'.

```
function test_search()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $this->db->select('user_items.*,item_data.*');
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT( emails.email SEPARATOR "," ) AS emails', FALSE);
    $this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT( IF(emailed.email,"YES","NO") SEPARATOR "," ) AS emailed', FALSE);

    $this->db->where('user_items.name','test');
    $this->db->join('item_data','user_items.name = item_data.name','LEFT');
    $this->db->join('emails','item_data.added = emails.added','LEFT');
    $this->db->join('emailed','emails.email = emailed.email','LEFT');
    $this->db->group_by('user_items.name');
    $res = $this->db->get('user_items');

    print_r($res->result_array());
}
```

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

This is really complex sql - is this really the best way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks

UPDATE

Following on from Cryode's excellent answer.

The only thing wrong with it is that it only returns one email. By using GROUP_CONCAT however I have been able to get all emails and all email_verified statuses into a string which I can then explode with PHP.

To clarify is the subquery,

```
SELECT item, MAX(added) AS added
            FROM item_data
            GROUP BY item
```

essentially creating a temporary table?

Similar to that outlined [here](http://murrayhopkins.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/mysql-left-join-on-last-or-first-record-in-the-right-table/)

Surely the subquery is necessary to make sure you only get one row from item_data - the most recent one?

And finally to answer the notes about the poorly designed database.

The database was designed this way as item_data is changed regularly but we want to keep historical records.

The emails are part of the item data but because there can be any number of emails, and we wanted them to be searchable we opted for a seperate table. Otherwise the emails would have to be serialized within the item_data table.

The emails_verified table is seperate as an email can be associated with more than one item.

Given that, although (clearly) complicated for querying it still seems a suitable setup..?

Thanks

FINAL UPDATE

Cryodes answer is a really useful answer relating to database architecture in general.

Having conceptualised this a little more, if we store the version id in user_items we dont need the subquery.

Because none of the data between versions is necessarily consistent we will scrap his proposed items table(for this case).
We can then get the correct version from a item_data tables
We can also get the items_version_emails rows based on the version id and from this get the respective emails from our 'emails' table.

I.E It works perfectly.

The downside of this is that when I add new version data in item_data I have to update the user_items table with the new version that has been inserted.

This is fine, but simply as a generalized point what is quicker?
I assume the reason such a setup has been suggested is that it is quicker - an extra update each time new data is added is worth it to save potentially hundreds of subqueries when lots of rows are being displayed. Especially given that we display the data more than we update it.

Just for knowledge when in future designing database architecture does anyone have any links/general guidance on what is quicker and why such that we can all make better optimized databases.

Thanks again to Cryode !!

Comment: Could you please post the **expected result** of such query in a table form based on your sample data?

Comment: You should be using integer keys between tables when possible. They are much more efficient than strings. Keys referenced between tables need to be indexed. With that you should be able to successfully use joins to get what you want.

Comment: `It is however very much 'im not too sure what im doing'.` **Define it** What is wrong with te above code? __A bad design none the less__

Comment: The expected output is posted above already. I am appreciative of the integer key efficiency - I will change this in the future. I am aware that it can be done with joins, it is simply how. My problem with the above code is that when it joins with item_data it gets both rows and thus concats the emails for both the old and new item_data entry. I only want the data for the most recent entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your database structure, this is what I came up with:

```
   SELECT ui.name, id.added, id.info, emails.email,
          CASE WHEN ev.id IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS email_verified
     FROM user_items AS ui
     JOIN item_data AS id ON id.item = ui.name
     JOIN (
            SELECT item, MAX(added) AS added
            FROM item_data
            GROUP BY item
        ) AS id_b ON id_b.item = id.item AND id_b.added = id.added
     JOIN emails ON emails.added = id.added
LEFT JOIN emails_verified AS ev ON ev.email = emails.email
```

But as others have pointed out, the database is poorly designed. This query will not perform well on a table with a lot of data, since there are no aggregate functions for this purpose. I understand that in certain situations you have little to no control over database design, but if you want to actually create the best situation, you should be emphatic to whomever *can* control it that it can be improved.

One of the biggest optimizations that could be made is to add the current `item_data` ID to the `user_items` table. That way the subquery to pull that wouldn't be necessary (since right now we're essentially joining `item_data` twice).

Converting this to CI's query builder is kind of a pain in the ass because of the sub query. Assuming you're only working with MySQL DBs, just stick with `$this->db->query()`.

**Added from your edit:**

This query returns one email per row, it does not group them together. I left the `CONCAT` stuff out because it's one more thing that slows down your query -- your PHP can put the emails together afterwards much faster.

Yes, the subquery is that part -- a query within a query (pretty self-explanatory name :wink:). I wouldn't call it creating a temporary table, because that's something you can actually do. More like retrieving a subset of the information in the table, and using it kind of like a `WHERE` clause. The subquery is what finds the most recent row in your `item_data` table, since we have to figure it out ourselves (again, proper database design would eliminate this).

When we say you can optimize your database design, it doesn't mean you can't have it set up in a similar way. You made it sound like the DB could not be altered *at all*. You have the right idea as far as the overall scheme, you're just implementing it poorly.

**Database Design**

Here's how I would lay this out. Note that without knowing the whole extent of your project, this may need modification. May also not be 100% the best optimized on the planet -- I'm open for suggestions for improvement. Your mileage may vary.

#### User Items

```
CREATE TABLE `users_items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Defines the relationship between a base item and a user.

#### Items

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `current_version` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Your items table should have all of your items' base information -- things that will not change on a per-revision basis. Notice the `current_version` column -- this is where you'll store the ID from the versions table, indicating which is most recent (so we don't have to figure it out ourselves).

#### Items Versions (history)

```
CREATE TABLE `items_versions` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `info` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is where you'd store the history of an item -- each update would create a new row here. Note that the `item_id` column is what ties this row to a particular base item.

#### Emails

```
CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Since emails can be shared between multiple products, we'll end up using what's called a **many-to-many** relationship. Emails can be tied to multiple products, and a product can be tied to multiple emails. Here we defined our emails, and include a `verified` column for whether it has been verified or not.

#### Item Emails

```
CREATE TABLE `items_versions_emails` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Assuming the emails are tied to an item version and not the base item, this is the structure you want. Unfortunately, if you have a ton of versions and never change the email(s), this will result in a lot of repeated data. So there's room for optimization here. If you tie emails to the base item, you'll have less repeated data, but you'll lose the history. So there's options for this. But the goal is to show how to set up DB relationships, not be 100% perfect.

That should give you a good start on how to better lay out your DB structure.

**Another Update**

Regarding speed, inserting a new item version and then updating the related item row with the new version ID will give you much better performance than requiring a subquery to pull the latest update. You'll notice in the solution for your original structure, the `item_info` table is being joined twice -- once to join the most recent rows, and again to grab the rest of the data from that recent row (because of the way `GROUP BY` works, we can't get it in a single join). If we have the recent version ID stored already, we don't need the first join at all, which will improve your speed dramatically (along with proper indexing, but that's another lesson).

I wouldn't recommend ditching the base `items` table, but that's really up to you and your application's needs. Without a base item, there's no real way to track the history of that particular item. There's nothing in the versions that shows a common ancestor/history, assuming you're removing the `item_id` column.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks a lot. I have followed up with an edit to the initial question which may help others with similar problems. If you could follow up/clarify those points that would be great but your help/knowledge is appreciated none the less.

Comment: Updated to answer your questions and sch00l you on DB design. :-p

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for spending the time making things clearer for me !

Comment: Added a tiny bit more about general database architecture. Sorry. I promise i'll leave you alone now. Thanks again.

Comment: I wouldn't get rid of the base item, because you'll lose the reference for that item's history.